# Using .try with ["posted-field"] rather than symbol :posted-field

Tags: sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

> I am using Sinatra.
>
> -I am receiving webhooks from a 3rd party.
>
> -The fields sent form the webhook vary from post to post.
>
> -I am using the syntax ["field"] rather than [:field] for the par in my model due to it being a Sinatra app.

```
Model

 def self.fields_hash_from_data(d)
{
field1: d["payload"]["some-field"]["that-appeared-in-this-webhook"]
field2: d["payload"]["some-field"]["that-did-not-appear-in-this-webhook"]
}
end

Controller

def method
  json = request.body.read
   data = JSON.parse(json)
     new_values = data.map do |d| 
     Model.fields_hash_from_data(d)
     end 
   Model.create(new_values_for_telematics)
end
```

> -I cannot use .try with this syntax- ["field"] because all the fields appear as nil, even when they have values.
>
> -If i do not use .try, undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass appears for the empty fields
>
> Is there an alternative to .try I can use in this case?

Comment: can you give an example on how you tried using try? It should normally work with hashes as well...

Comment: the correct syntax would be d.try(:[], "payload")...

Comment: alternatively you can use try using the fetch method: d.try(:fetch, "payload")

Comment: @tpei long overdue, but you got this right, so thank you :)